# Bug installing tex/latex/texlive packages makes subsystem unusable

Tags: apt, package-management, latex

#### I am having problems installing tex/latex/texlive packages on 12.04.

My setup:

```
> cat /etc/issue; uname -a
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-33-generic-pae #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 18 16:39:21 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I tried starting from scratch:

```
apt-get purge $(dpkg --get-selections | cut -f 1 | grep --color=never '^tex\|tex$' | paste -s -d ' ')
```

But trying to install things:

```
apt-get install texlive-base
```

still fails:

```
> dpkg --status texlive-base
Package: texlive-base
Status: install ok half-configured
```

This might be related to bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=648278

but the solution there does not fix the issue for me!

Dump of `apt-get install textlive-base` @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/1400458/

Dump of `dpkg --configure -a 2>&1` @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/1400609/

Dump of `dpkg-query --status texlive-base` @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/1400638/

Dump of `/etc/libpaper.d/texlive-base` @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/1400645/

Comment: Please include the full output from `apt-get install texlive-base`

Comment: Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1400458/

Comment: `texlive-base`'s postinst script is failing. I suggest putting a set -x near the top of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/texlive-base.postinst` and running `dpkg --configure -a`. Maybe that'll help show what the problem is.

Comment: Good idea, here's the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1400609/ I can't interpret it, does it tell _you_ anything?

Comment: I [asked on chat.tex.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8018012#8018012) and got the answer you might first install `xdvi` and `dvips`. Could you try this and report if it helps?

Comment: It seems this question is abandoned. So I'll vote to cloe it.

Comment: I did answer all of the questions in the comments..

Comment: @Robottinosino Actually you didn't answer the [last comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/222560/bug-installing-tex-latex-texlive-packages-makes-subsystem-unusable#comment315814_222560). At least that is what I can see here, I don't know if you did that in the chat..

Comment: Ah, the installation? It did not help.